# How to import pyd files into Maya

Tags: python

I used the PYTHON official compiler to generate PYD files, but when the PYD file is imported into Maya2017 in windows10, an error will occur.

```
> # Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
> # Traceback (most recent call last):
> #   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
> # ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried installing cython for mayapy, it did get installed but when I try to compile a script I get this: error: Cython does not appear to be installed

I tried installing it for a regular python interpreter and appending the site-package to mayapy's path, which gave me the same error.

I have installed cython in both python and mayapy editors.

I have installed VS2017 and modified the settings in ‘C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2017\bin\python27.zip’ (sysconfig.py and msvc9compiler.py)

At the same time, I also set the system environment variables(PYTHONPATH and VS15).

I found a lot of websites and tried a lot of methods, but still failed, I am very depressed.

If you know, please tell me how to correctly import the generated pyd file into Maya, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi，everyone，I am very happy to tell you.I have found the answer. The reason is that Visual Studio corresponds to the different versions of MAYA, so you can solve the problem by finding the corresponding version. I installed VS2012 update4 to compile pyd that can load it in Maya.
Thanks Preadtor and Foley for helping me.

[Compiler versions for Maya 2017](https://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2016/08/compiler-versions-for-maya-2017.html?tdsourcetag=s_pcqq_aiomsg)

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more on how to compile the .pyd files? I have the source code for the module and the correct visual studio version but I dont know which files im supposed to compile